# ¿Qué significa el símbolo "?" en PHP?

Tags: php

Verán, me he encontrado con la siguiente línea de código y no logro determinar el funcionamiento del símbolo de interrogación.

¿Podrían ayudarme a interpretar la línea, y de ser posible, dejar una breve descripción del funcionamiento del símbolo (Para otros que tengan la misma pregunta)?

```
parent::generic_input_text('contactName', (isset($item['s_contact_name'])) ? $item['s_contact_name'] : null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es parte del operador ternario de PHP.  En tu ejemplo llamas a una funcion `generic_input_test` que recibe dos parametros.  En el segundo parametro esta la siguiente condicion:

```
isset($item['s_contact_name'])) ? $item['s_contact_name'] : null
```

Que significa: "Si el valor `$item['s_contact_name']` existe, pasalo como parametro, sino existe pasale `null`"

Answer (score 2):

el `?` es un condicional es el equivalente de `if else` conocido como `shorthand`

```
 if(condicion) { /* si retorna true */} 
 else { /* en caso de false */}

(condicion) ? /* si retorna true */ 
            : /* en caso de false */ ;
```

ahora un ejemplo:

**version clasica o normal**

```
$variable =true;

if($variable){
   echo "soy un true";
}else{
   echo "ups! soy false";
}

// asignacion de valor:
if($variable){
   $resultado= "soy un true";
}else{
   $resultado= "ups! soy false";
}
echo $result;
```

**version con shorthand**

```
$variable =true;
echo $variable ? "soy un true" : "ups! soy false";

// asignando valor a una variable
$resultado= $variable ? "soy un true" : "ups! soy false";
echo $resultado;
```

> **nota** no confundir con el operador de fusión de null `??` que devuelve su primer operando si existe y no es NULL; de lo contrario devuelve su segundo operando y asi sucesivamente. eliminando el utilizar un operador ternario junto con isset(). incluida en  `php version 7`

**ejemplo:**

```
$variable ="hola...";
$resultado= $variable2 ?? $variable3 ?? $variable;
echo $resultado;

$resultado = $variable2 ?? $variable3 ?? "ninguna de las primera existe";
echo $resultado;
```

**tu codigo:**

```
parent::generic_input_text('contactName', ( $item['s_contact_name'] ?? null);
```